# Find out number of installs of a package

Tags: go

Let's say that I want to figure out how many programmers import https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate, similar to how I can figure it out for npm package [on this website](https://www.npmtrends.com/).

I know that you can guess the popularity of a package from the number of github stars, commmits etc, but I think installs count gives the most accurate picture of how popular a package is. Go package loading method is different from npm, so I wonder if it's even possible to get such intel?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Given the `go` tool doesn't collect/send this metric, no.

There is a different metric tracked on [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev) that shows how many other packages import the package in question.

When you open a package page (e.g. [migrate](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate)) on the same line next to the version, license there is also *Imported By* with number. You can see detailed list of importers (only those known to pkg.go.dev site) on page it [links to](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate?tab=importedby).

[image]

While this is not same thing npm does it can give you a rough idea of package popularity.

Answer (score 0):

https://godoc.org/ shows the number of package imports right under the package name on searching for the package.

For e.g., when you search for the fmt package, it shows it has been imported 827695 times as of 23 January, 2021. This is close to the functionality of the npm site that you have referenced.